# Viewing 3D shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, 3d

I have 3D shapefile which displays fine in QGIS 2D (and 3D in ArcScene), but I am having trouble changing to 3D view in QGIS. Shapefile is an imported polygon set (in a local CRS) > I get the message 'layer extent invalid'.

How do I fix this for my local CRS?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the layer to a different CRS? If so, what happens then? Are the geometries on the layer all valid?

Comment: Thank you - yes- I have how got the CRS aspect correct, but I still cant get 3D (Z) displayed in a  'new 3d view'...have asked a new question in this regard

Answer (score 0):

My problem here was initially resolved by going back to source data and converting to a projected CRS before importing to QGIS (not perfect because data was local grid in origin- but good enough)

I am still unable to see 3D (z) in QGIS - just a 2D projection on to the 3D viewer base plane, and I have asked new question about that...

Comment: I believe you need either a "Raster (DEM) or mesh layer to be used for generation of the 3D." in QGIS. Then you can view your 3D shape in 3D. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#terrain